# Convert enum with duplicate underlying value to dictionary of string and enum

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I'm working on a project that requires to load a JSON configuration file, parse it with Newtonsoft.JSON and extract the values. Some of the key-value-paris have to be mapped to a Enum and the result should be a `Dictionary<string, enumType>`. One of these enums is `System.Drawing.RotateFlipType`. But because this enum has 16 member with 8 member sharing the underlying value with one other member, the `ToDictionary` methode throws an `System.ArgumentException` because "there is already a element with the same key".

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
var rotationTypesDict = Enum
                        .GetValues(typeof(RotateFlipType))
                        .Cast<RotateFlipType>()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => x);
```

Problem here is the return type of the Linq query: `Dictionary<string, RotateFlipType>`. Since `ToString()` applied on RotationFlipType with the underlying value of 0 resolves only "RotateNoneFlipNone" even though "Rotate180FlipXY" also has the underlying value of "0". So I'm wondering of there is any chance to get this done.

I also tried the other way around to use `Enum.GetNames()` and `ToDictionary()` The `ToDictionary` metode returns the key as string (as expected) but the value has the same problem as before. When using the string "RotateNoneFlipNone" to lookup the underlying value it get the value 0 which gets me the `RotationFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone` member. Perfect! But when using the string "Rotate180FlipXY" the underlying value is also "0" which gives me the member `RotationFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone` which is wrong in this case. (Wrong because if in the config file the user wants to use the RotationFlipType "Rotate180FlipXY" then the program searches for this value in the dictionary and doesn't find it.)

Edit: As JonasH requested, I try to explain what I want.
The goal is to get a Dictionary<string, RotationFlipType> where the key is the name of the member and the value equals to the underlying value of the member.
This is required because the configurationfile is exported from another program which displays the possible RotationFlipTypes in a Combobox. And since the value to be exported is retrieved by calling `SelectedItem.ToString()` from the Combobox, if I select the RotationFlipType "Rotate180FlipXY" it is technically identical to RotationFlipType "RotateNoneFlipNone, but the configfile will contain "Rotate180FlipXY". So when reading and parsing the config file and looking up for "Rotate180FlipXY" there will be no result since when I'm only including entries with a unique underlying value the member "RotateNoneFlipNone" and "Rotate180FlipXY" will be condensed to "RotateNoneFlipNone". Sry for the one-liner

Comment: you grouped them and return `Dictionary<string, IList<RotateFlipType>>`

Comment: It is not very clear to me what the actual goal is here. If `RotateNoneFlipNone` has the same value as `Rotate180FlipXY`, then they are the same. If you do not want them to be the same thing, they should have different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GetNames` and `GetValues` return always in the same order, you can use `Zip` to join them together. Let's top this off by making it a generic function:

```cs
public Dictionary<string, T> GetEnumDict<T>() where T : struct //, System.Enum if on C# 7.3
{
    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
        .Zip(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)),
            (n, v) => (n, (T)v))
        .ToDictionary(
            nv => nv.n,
            nv => nv.v
    );
}

var rotationTypesDict = GetEnumDict<RotateFlipType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var rotationTypesDict = Enum
    .GetNames(typeof(RotateFlipType))
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x,
        x => Enum.TryParse(x, out RotateFlipType y)
            ? y
            : throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Should never happen."));
```